# `drush up` Eventually Asks For a Password. Why?

Tags: drush

I am new to using drush's fancier features. Today I was hoping to make my life easy for a core update by using the all inclusive `drush up` command.

While logged in via ssh, the terminal displays that server's user like the following example

```
serveruser [~/public_html/staging/sites/all]# drush up
```

Of all of drush's commands that I have used before, none required a password. `drush sqlc` for example doesn't prompt one, therefore I know that it knows the sql user and password. Running `drush up` however eventually prompted for a password, but not for the `serveruser`! Instead it asked for a password for user `wray`.

What password is this supposed to be for?

Answer (score 1):

By default, using `drush up` will do a database dump as a backup. That's what the docs will tell you. They will also tell you that if drush finds an SVN repository anywhere it will try to use it. When it finds that SVN repository, it might ask for your SVN password. Drush isn't very smart about what that SVN repository was actually being used for. So to disable that feature and force it back in to the default database dump you have to append the default setting back on to the drush command like so:

```
drush up --version-control=backup
```